# Why is my "em" font-sizing not accurate based on what I set?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, font-size

I'm trying to figure out why `em` font sizing is not behaving the way it should when `body` font size is set to 10 pixels. in other words it's like there's a 9px minimum font size applied to elements unless I overwrite it with a pixel value. Can anyone explain why is this happening?

For more clarification: I've set `html`'s `font-size` to `62.5%` for accessibility, which on default settings on most browsers is equal to `10px`. I also set `body` font size to `1em` which inherently is equal to `10px`. I have 3 paragraphs which have `em` font sizes. If you try to inspect the `p` elements in chrome and go to the "computed" tab in dev tools, you'll see that the first paragraph that has a `font-size` of `1em` is computed to `10px` (as expected). But the other two paragraphs' `font-size` is computed to `9px`, which I expect them to be `8px` and `6px`. It's like there's `9px` minimum font size applied and the only way to overwrite it is to apply a `px` font size to it.

P.S: I've experienced this in Chrome Version 40.0.2214.111, this also happens in latest safari on OS X Yosemite.

```css
html {
  font-size:62.5%;
  padding:3em;
}
body { font-size:1em; }

._10 {
  font-size:1em;
}
._8 {
  font-size:0.8em;
}
._6 {
  font-size:0.6em;
}
```

```html
<p class="_10">1x10 = 10</p>
<p class="_8">0.8x10 = 9 (!)</p>
<p class="_6">0.6x10 = 9 (!)</p>
```

Comment: It seems to work in Chrome. What browser are you using.

Comment: Browsers may indeed have a minimum font size setting, controllable by the user. But they apply also to sizes set in pixels. Please clarify your question and describe exactly how you inferred what the actual sizes are, and on which browser(s).

Comment: @bobdye not sure, but I think you need to inspect it in chrome to see the difference

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I've added more information to the question

Comment: It sounds like your copy of Chrome has minimum font size set to 9px (which is a useful setting, since anything smaller tends to be rather illegible). This matches the symptoms except that the minimum cannot be overridden on a page be setting font size in pixels.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I think your's is the correct answer. If you would like to submit it I will select it as the correct answer. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like this could be an inheritance issue -

em will refer to the parent container, and adjust size based on that.

If you'd like to always use the font-size set on your html or body element, use 'rem' which is **root**

This article helps break it down: https://j.eremy.net/confused-about-rem-and-em/